# How to do this giant join in sqlite

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I am using Python3 to analyze some data from an sqlite database file.  I want to join all the tables together into one giant table in Python.  I know a bit about the python commands to do this, but the sql statement is too complicated for me to understand, at all.  I need help creating the sql statement that I will execute on the database file.  I would also like all this data to be output as a pandas dataframe as well.

In the sqlite file I have the following tables:

```
station
     id
     name
     lat
     long
     dock_count
     city
     installation_date
status
     station_id
     bikes_available
     docks_available
     time
trip
     id
     duration
     start_date
     start_station_name
     start_station_id
     end_date
     end_station_name
     end_station_id
     bike_id
     subscription_type
     zip_code
weather
     date
     max_temperature_f
     mean_temperature_f
     min_temperature_f
     max_dew_point_f
     mean_dew_point_f
     min_dew_point_f
     max_humidity
     mean_humidity
     min_humidity
     max_sea_level_pressure_inches
     mean_sea_level_pressure_inches
     min_sea_level_pressure_inches
     max_visibility_miles
     mean_visibility_miles
     min_visibility_miles
     max_wind_Speed_mph
     mean_wind_speed_mph
     max_gust_speed_mph
     precipitation_inches
     cloud_cover
     events
     wind_dir_degrees
     zip_code
```

I want to join all the tables into one giant table and then select 1000 trips with all the joined data.  This means I need to know some foreign keys in the trip table and here they are:

```
start_date, points to weather, status

start_station_id, points to station

end_date, points to weather, status

end_station_id points to station
```

The join I am thinking of is the following:

```
select 1000 rows from trip join (

weather where trip.start_date = weather.date as startweather

) and join (

weather where trip.end_date = weather.date as endweather

) and join (

station where trip.start_station_id = station.id as startstation

)  and join(

station where trip.end_station_id = station.id as endstation

) and join (

status where trip.start_station_id = station.status_id and trip.start_date = station.date as startstationstatus

) and join(

status where trip.end_station_id = station.status_id and trip.end_date = station.date as endstationstatus)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post an answer to this question because the query that I eventually got working shows a number of different features of sqlite.  Here is the query that I used:

```
Select count() FROM trip as tr INNER JOIN station as startst on startst.id = tr.start_station_id INNER JOIN station as endst on endst.id = tr.end_station_id INNER JOIN weather as startwea on startwea.date = SUBSTR(tr.start_date,1,9) INNER JOIN status as ststat on trim(substr(ststat.time, 6, 2), "0") = substr(tr.start_date, 1, instr(tr.start_date,"/") - 1) and trim(substr(ststat.time, 9, 2), "0") = substr(tr.start_date, instr(tr.start_date,"/") + 1, instr(substr(tr.start_date, instr(tr.start_date,"/") + 1),"/") - 1) and substr(ststat.time, 1, 4) = substr(tr.start_date, instr(tr.start_date, " "), -4) WHERE tr.id  > 0 AND tr.id <= 7000000 AND tr.id % 100000 = 0
```

It is overly complicated at the end because I had to join two tables by a date column and the date was formatted differently in each column.